# Добавить пользователю сайта возможность опубликовывать что он хочет

Tags: python, django, site

Вообщем, как вы поняли, я в программировании новичок. Я изучаю фреймворк Django. У меня вопрос, как реализовать возможность пользователям "опубликовывать" на мой сайт чтобы это ни было, вместо того чтобы переходить на уже готовый сайт, где нельзя ничего добавлять. Тоесть сделать своеобразную площадку. Лучше понять на примерах. Далеко ходить не надо, стаковерфлоу, на этом сайте пользователь может задать **свой** вопрос. Алиэкспресс, Авито, ОЛХ, Амазон - люди размещают **свои** товары. Хабр - люди публикуют **свои** статьи. Надеюсь объяснил нормально. Подскажите как это реализовано пожалуйста, либо скиньте статью.

Comment: "**Невозможно дать объективный ответ**:
Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе."

Comment: Рекомендую книгу: Django For Beginners.

Comment: @Victor Хорошо, как реализовано связь заказчиков с исполнителями на биржах фриланса (когда можно выкладывать свои объявления)

Comment: Этот вопрос не формат для сайта. Вы предлагаете сделать за вас? Идеи как сделать данны вот в книге. Или погуглите и читайте.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica я нашел эту книгу, можете подсказать на какой главе мне примерно искать

Comment: Читай все подряд, не перескакивай:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте форму для ввода новых данных и дайте тем самым возможность создавать контент. Если только начали изучать джанго, то терпения - это гдето в последней трети обучения.